# The tokenizer Doesn't recognize the new special tokens

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

When I run the code below, the tokenizer doesn't recognize the new special tokens that I added ([SP] and [EMPTY]). I wanted to tokenize arabic text.

```
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer
from transformers import BertTokenizer

vocab_size=50_000
#vocab_size=30522

tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer(clean_text=True, handle_chinese_chars=False,                       strip_accents=False, lowercase=False)
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/text.txt'

tokenizer.train(files=path, vocab_size = vocab_size, min_frequency=5, limit_alphabet=1000, wordpieces_prefix='##', special_tokens=['[PAD]', '[UNK]', '[CLS]', '[SEP]', '[MASK]', '[SP]', '[EMPTY]'])

tokenizer.save_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/', 'new')  # 'new-vocab.txt'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/new-vocab.txt')

sen = "[CLS] تم اجتياز الامتحان بنجاح [SP] [EMPTY] [SEP]"
display(tokenizer.tokenize(sen))
```

This is the output:

```
\['\[CLS\]',
'تم',
'اجت',
'##ياز',
'الامتحان',
'بنج',
'##اح',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[UNK\]',
'\[SEP\]'\]
```

Comment: Having a similar problem at the moment...